# Cp -Verbose outputs stating the file is copied, but the file actually doesn't show up

Tags: cp

Facing a strange problem. 
I tried running cp command in a script (Debian Lenny - Loaded with KDE).The verbose throws a message as if the file is copied but the file actually doesn't get copied until I manually refresh the destination folder.

Here is the copy command that I am trying to execute:
cp -v /data/publish/${VAR1}.txt ${VAR2}

FYI: VAR2- Variable holding the path to destination folder. In this case happens to be a usb drive.

The reason I call it a strange problem, is because I have no problems while executing this piece in Ubuntu, but facing problem in an another box running debian (loaded with KDE 3.5, I understand its pretty outdated).

Please help guys!

Comment: So does it not get copied or the OS doesn't show the item until you refresh the view? Can you clarify please. At the end of your first paragraph it seems like it is indeed copying but you don't see it in the file viewer (gui interface) until you hit refresh.

Comment: Also does the destination path include the file name?

Comment: @CalebB, it does not get copied at all. I immediately unplugged the usb drive after executing the script and checked it another box running windows, the file isn't there. Nope the path doesn't contain the file name.

Comment: There's your problem. According to the [documentation](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm) You need the new file name included in the path when using the cp command.

Comment: In addition you could use watch to monitor the copying process to see when the copying is complete.

Comment: @CalebB, I will give it a try tomorrow, don't have access to the system right now. The copying process happens in a flash inside a system running ubuntu. (I generally keep a watch by opening the destination folder window to monitor the process)

Comment: Alright, also for future reference there is a section of stackexchange called [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) that may be better for these types of inquiries.